# .bind this in class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to learn how react is made and I stumbled upon this great video on youtube. Here he have done something like this.

First we have created a `createElement` function of react

```
function createElement (el, props, ...children ) {
    return div(el,props,children)
}

   function div (el, props, children) {
        // checking if element is class 
            if (isClass(el)) {
                return HandleClass(el, props)
       // more code but skipping adding it since it is irrelevant

function HandleClass (classComponent, props) {
    const component = new classComponent(props)
    return component.render()
} 

window.React = {
    createElement
}
```

And the React Class component which looks like this

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        }
    }

    onPlusClick () {
        this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1})
    }

    onMinusClick () {
        this.setState({value: this.state.value - 1})
    }


    render () {
        return React.createElement('div', null, 
        React.createElement('h1', null, 'This is famour foo counter app'),
        React.createElement('h1', null, `Counter Value: ${this.state.value}`),
        React.createElement('button', {onClick: this.onPlusClick.bind(this)}, '+'), //TODO: What does .bind here mean
        React.createElement('button', {onClick: this.onMinusClick.bind(this)}, '-')  //TODO: What does .bind here mean
        )
    }
}
```

Now, here I don't understand the `onClick: this.onMinusClick.bind(this)` (in above class). Can someone please explain it to me? In my personal react project, I never had to use bind to add click events

Thanks

Comment: follow the link - https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: This is not specific to react. Did you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained pretty well in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).  From the docs:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

In other words, any function you write as a method of your class doesn't know what `this` means when you use it within that function.  So with your class method `onPlusClick`, you ask it to `this.setState({ ... ])`.  But inside that method, it does not inherently know what `this` is referring to.  You have to *tell it* that you want the `this` inside the class method to refer to the class component you're currently inside of.  Hence the need for the `bind` statement.

You may never have needed to use `bind` before if you were using an arrow function.  Arrow functions *preserve the context of `this`*, meaning when you use the word `this` inside an arrow function, it automatically assumes the meaning of `this` is the same as it is in the context of where your arrow funtion was written.

Hopefully that clears it up for you.

Answer (score -1):

Every function in react must be binded, or else it wont work. Or else when you call it it will give an error
You can do this too:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        value: 0
    }
this.onPlusClick = this.onPlusClick.bind(this);
this.onMinusClick= this.onMinusClick.bind(this);
}

onPlusClick () {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1})
}

onMinusClick () {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value - 1})
}


render () {
    return React.createElement('div', null, 
    React.createElement('h1', null, 'This is famour foo counter app'),
    React.createElement('h1', null, `Counter Value: ${this.state.value}`),
    React.createElement('button', {onClick: this.onPlusClick}, '+'), //TODO: What does .bind here mean
    React.createElement('button', {onClick: this.onMinusClick}, '-')  //TODO: What does .bind here mean
    )
}
```

}